# Mongo aggregate function

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent

It must be a very stupid question but I am unable to fetch a date key in the mongo aggregate function in laravel framework I used this query to fetch the records but I am not getting how to store the "ts" key in the records too.

```
$records = $this->raw()->aggregate([
    ['$match' =>  ["ts" => ['$gte'=>  $startTime,'$lt'=>  $endTime]]],
    ['$group' => ["_id" =>["config" => '$conf', "status" => '$s'], "count" =>['$sum' =>1]]],
])->toArray();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Here you've named `ts` as `_id.date`. What do you need to do with this?

Comment: @apokryfos sorry I stated the wrong query. updated

Comment: I wanted to know how will I get ts field in the records too

Comment: The problem is `$group` will group a set of documents so it will have multiple `ts` values in the group. You can add `ts` to the `_id` but that will make more groups. Which ts of each group do you want to store?

Comment: @apokryfos lets say i have to store $startTime in $records (not ts because there would be multiple ts entries)

Comment: I "think" `"_id" =>["config" => '$conf', "status" => '$s', 'startTime' => $startTime]` would work (note `$startTime` here is the PHP variable itself which will be passed as a literal)